# Minima of a quadratic expression

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have a sequence of $n$ integers, $p_k$, with $0\le k<n$.

Is it possible to find the minima of $(j-k)^2+p_j^2,0\le j<n$ for all $k$ in linear time ?

---

If it can help, this is equivalent to finding the minima of

$$j^2+p_j^2-2jk$$ or simply $$q_j-2jk$$ where $q_j\ge j^2$.

---

**Update**:

If I am right, the last formulation corresponds to the search of the lowest tangency points of lines of slope $2k$ to the graph of $q_j$. This problem is in direct relation to the construction of the lower hull of the curve.

Comment: If $k$ is fixed (or arbitrary) in the second paragraph, maybe it'd be better to use $j$ instead in the first one.

Comment: The minimum (over $j$) must be found for every $k$, and the whole process in linear time.

Comment: Are we assuming operations on integers are all constant time? Any other constraints on the processing model?

Comment: @JohnHughes: you can assume real arithmetic, in constant time (incuding square root and floor...).

Comment: Consider the case $p_0  = 1; p_1 = 0$. Then for $k = 0$, $(0-0)^2 + p_0^2 = 1 = (1-0)^2 + p_1^2$, so there are two indices that achieve the minimum. Do you merely want to know the minimum, or do you want to know the index where the min is achieved? If the latter...is it OK to pick *any* index at which the min is achieved?

Comment: Any index is fine.

Comment: Just curious, why did you say $n$ integers when there are $n+1$?

Comment: @Ovi: because there are $n$.

Comment: Ah yes sorry my mistake.